# Aptos Move conflicting dependencies of imported dependencies

Tags: move-lang, aptos

I have two dependencies that I need, they both created a module called U256 with different addresses. is there a way to fix this dependency conflict?

`Unable to resolve package dependency 'U256': Conflicting dependencies found: package 'U256' conflicts with 'U256'"`

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. For example, please give us the Move.toml and source files that you're using that results in this problem. As it is now, there isn't much advice we can give beyond "don't use the conflicting deps".

Answer (score 0):

The address system of aptos module is based on `{address}::{module_name}::{struct_name}`.

Here U256 you mentioned here is just for `{struct_name}`.
I think you have some misunderstanding on importing correct dependency.